# URDF tutorial help

Tags: urdf

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to learn ROS and URDF.

I am looking into [this](http://wiki.ros.org/urdf/Tutorials/Building%20a%20Visual%20Robot%20Model%20with%20URDF%20from%20Scratch) tutorial but I am immediately lost at the second step where I am supposed to execute the launch file.

In other words, I'm supposed to execute :

```
> $ roslaunch urdf_tutorial display.launch model:=urdf/01-myfirst.urdf
```

But the tutorial does not indicate what display.launch is nor what it contains. I executed **`catkin_create_pkg my_robot`** and my code looks like the following:

```
my_robot
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── package.xml
└── urdf
    └── 01-myfirst.urdf
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/276511/urdf-tutorial-help/) by [sisko](https://answers.ros.org/users/32731/sisko/) on ROS Answers with karma: 247 on 2017-11-23

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It's referring to [urdf_tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/urdf_tutorial) package. You can install it with `sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-urdf-tutorial`.

---

Originally posted by [l4ncelot](https://answers.ros.org/users/23971/l4ncelot/) with karma: 826 on 2017-11-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sisko](https://answers.ros.org/users/32731/sisko/) on 2017-11-23**:
Thank you for for your input.

Perhaps because I'm using Indigo, your suggested code did not work.

However, I executed `sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-urdf-tutorial` and the package installed.
I now have *urdf_tutorial*.

Appreciated!

**Comment by [l4ncelot](https://answers.ros.org/users/23971/l4ncelot/) on 2017-11-23**:
Can you mark the answer as correct and close the question?